# Buildozer error : Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "randomapp"

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I have a simple project written in python (kivy) and i am using buildozer to make .apk file for Android platform. But for some reason the compiling it's not sucessufull. I think it's a problem with the pythoh-for-android module because it gives me the error:

```
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "randomapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

But when i added log_level = 2 , i see that it says that lpng is missing:

```
 /home/shakle17/shakle/rand0m/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/bui/home/shakle17/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Fedora23 and i've installed all libraries (libpng , libpng-devel for x64 and i686 platform) in the dnf package manager but still the problem remains .

Comment: It looks like some PNG library (maybe the dev package) has to be installed on your system.

Comment: Like i've said i've installed libpng , libpng-devel both x64 and i686 versions plus other x-png or png-x modules, but still the problem remains

Comment: It's probably that libpng is missing in the Android build, not on your system. Post the full log.

Comment: Here is a pastebin , because it couldn't allow more than 15k characters or sth  http://pastebin.com/AixF46JK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it . I've installed libpng from the official site, than run : `buildozer android clean` and after that it was fixed